# Why is the output different in the short version of if condition when compared to its expanded version?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
int a = 0;
a = 7 > 2 ? printf("6") : printf("4");
printf ("%d",a);
```

### The ouput of this block is :

```
61
```

I tried the code in its expanded form

```
    int a = 0  ;
    if(7>2)
    {
        printf("6");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("4");
    }
    printf("%d",a);
```

### Here I the output was:

```
60
```

I would like to get an explanation on why the output differs.

Comment: First one assigns to `a`, second does not.

Comment: %d is converting the bool true (result of 7>2) to 1.

Comment: @IgnacioGaviglio `7>2` gives a result of type `int` and value `1`. No conversion takes place. Maybe you are mixing up C and C++. Furthermore, `%d` doesn't lead to a conversion from bool to int, the variadic printf function is what causes the conversion, through something called _default argument promotions_ = small integer types get converted to `int`.

Comment: @Lundin You are absolutely right. Keep forgetting that old c had no bools.

Comment: Side note: If anyone taught you that printing `\n` was an expensive operation, to be avoided if possible, meaning that it's often the user's job to interpret outputs like `62` as meaning a `6`, and a later `2`, having nothing to do with each other, and especially not anything like the number "sixty two" — please ignore that misguided advice.  In fact, printing `\n` costs almost nothing, and the benefit to any reader who therefore does *not* have to decode things, is immense!

Answer (score 2):

The first statement assigns the return value of `printf` to `a`. [printf returns](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE) the number of bytes that were written.  In this case that is 1.  In the second expanded version, `a` is not assigned.  Here is an *actually* equivalent version to the original:

```
int a = 0;
if(7>2)
{
    a = printf("6");
}
else
{
    a = printf("4");
}
printf("%d",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different.

To make them identical:

```
    int a = 0  ;
    if(7>2)
    {
        a = printf("6");
    }
    else
    {
        a = printf("4");
    }
    printf("%d",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cond?val1:val2` is the ternary operator. It is not supposed to be a control structure (like `if`, `for` or `while`). It is an operator. To build expression (things that have a value) rather than instruction (things that does things).
Frontier is fuzzier in C than in other languages, because instructions have a value (including `void`) and expression have potential side-effects.

But, well, you use `cond?val1:val2` when you want to get the result. As you did, since you assigned the result to `a`.

And the result here is the result of `printf("6")`, that is 1, since `printf` returns the number of printed characters. Note that there is no real doubt, since even if 7 were smaller than 2, result would still have been 1. Since you print that result, it is normal to have a `1` printed after the `6`.

(Just to be clear, even if I assume you know that already, what you did is print string "6" and then number 1, which is the result of 1st printf. Exactly as if you did

```c
printf("%d",printf("6"));
```

which 1st prints "6", then pass the result to the outer printf to print what the inner `printf` returned, that is 1)

In your second code, you do nothing to change `a`'s value, and you ignore the result of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples aren't equivalent. To be equivalent, the second one should say `a=printf(...` everywhere. After which `a` will get assigned the number of characters printed, `1`.